# What is the difference between “reenact” and “react”?

Tags: vocabulary

Can they be used in the same situation?I tried to find the answer on google but still don’t understand.

Comment: Usually you can get word meanings by searching for the word followed by "meaning."

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." This question is answered by looking in dictionaries, so is off topic anyway.

Answer (score 1):

They are not synonyms even though they are related by etymology.

"Reenact" means to do something again.

"React" means to do something as a response to something else.

Answer (score 0):

They look similar but they have totally different meanings.

To "react" is to do something in response to another event. Like, "Every time the boss walks into the room, I REACT by pretending to be busy."

To "reenact" is to recreate some past event. Like, "In my town there is a group who  dress up in 19th century uniforms and REENACT battles from the War of 1812."

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted your response. Presumably, the same person downvoted mine for the same unknown reason. I am upvoting yours.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Cool, I just upvoted yours, too. I don't mind when someone downvotes and posts some objection. Even if I don't think the objection is valid, at least I understand why. But in this case, I thought both of our answers were accurate and clear.

Comment: And cool on you as well. I feel the same.